# Angular sorting- not able to sort a column

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material-table

I am trying to enable sorting on a mat-table, and I understood that *matColumnDef and the binding element must have the same name.but, i have two binding elements in one ng-container.

Name 
          {{faculty.firstName}}  {{faculty.lastName}}

so, what matColumnDef name, should i give for sorting this field.